# List getting replaced

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, replication

I have the following piece of code

```
>>> no=[]
>>> matrix = [[[] for x in xrange(4)] for x in xrange(4)] 
>>> no=[2]
>>> temp = no
>>> matrix[1][2].append(temp)
>>> no.append(3)
>>> matrix[1][2]
```

when I print `matrix[1][2]` I am getting the following output:

```
[[2, 3]]
```

But what I want is:

```
[2]
```

So basically what is happening is the list is getting changed inside the matrix list if I change it afterwards.  But I don't want to get it changed

How can I do it ? And why is it happening ?

Comment: For matrices I would suggest looking into [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: This has to be a duplicate, but I can't find the original question anywhere. I need to bookmark it because new questions about it happen all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of no   `temp = no[:]`.

`temp = no` is just a reference to the same object so any changes in `no` will affect `temp`

A reference:

```
In [21]: my_l = [1,2,3]

In [22]: ref_my_l = my_l

In [23]: ref_my_l
Out[23]: [1, 2, 3]

In [24]: my_l.append(4)

In [25]: my_l
Out[25]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [26]: ref_my_l
Out[26]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A copy:

```
In [27]: my_l = [1,2,3]

In [28]: copy_my_l = my_l[:]

In [29]: my_l.append(4)

In [30]: my_l
Out[30]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [31]: copy_my_l
Out[31]: [1, 2, 3]
```